# What is the best way to read float and int from text file and put them into numpy/pandas array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, file, text

I have a text file with following structure (blanks in the beginning on purpose)

```
   * Some unimportant text line *

   Data set # 1

   Time   Data1    Data2
   [s]   [kg/m2]    [C]

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   1.0    2.45     465.5E-5
   2.0    3.76     876.6E-6
   ...

// empy lines between end of table to next line //

   Data set # 2

   ...
   ...
```

What I would like is to create a dictionary with key as point number ('1') and value is the float matrix which comes after that. Currently I'm using something like this:

```
results = []
num_of points = []
dict_results = {}
regex_pattern = r'-?\ *[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?:[Ee]\ *-?\ *[0-9]+)?'  # for all numbers

with ('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        test_line = re.findall (regex_pattern, line)
            if len(test_line) == 1:     # check if it is a data set line 
                if not num_of points:    # firts data set
                    current point = int (test_line)
                    num_of_points.append(current_point)
                else:
                    # append the data to dict 
                    results_array = np.array(results , dtype= float)
                    dict_results.update({num_of_points[-1] : results_array})
                    # reset the result list
                    results = []
                    # update the point list
                    current_point = int(test_line)                    
                    num_of_points.append(current_point) 
            elif len(test_line) == 3:        # check if it is a data line
                    results.append(test_line)
```

It seems to work but I wonder if there is a more elegant and efficient way to do it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How does expected dict look like? What is point number 1 and float matrix?

Comment: for the 1st data set it will be something like that : ` {'1' : ndarray(2,3)([ 1, 2.45 , 0.004655],[2.0 , 3.76, 0.0008766])}`